# Android studio installing APK on phone but can't find the app

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk

I am new to Android Studio and I am trying to deploy an APK to my mobile device in order to test the app. I build the APK successfully but when I install the apk of the app in my device I couldn't see it or cannot be open. But I can see the apps in the app manager showing that I installed it.

here is the code in my manifest file.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Pasig NutriCare"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe the app's Manifest is missing the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` intent filter declaration?

Comment: It worked on Emulator but not working on the device?. You need to Disable instant run and build the project again

Comment: please post your manifest file here

Comment: there. I edited it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you specify the launcher activity for the app in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".YOURACTIVITY" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I had two activity one is the splash screen and one is my main activity file which one would I select as the launcher? Sorry new in Android native

Comment: select splashscreen activity

Comment: then I would make the main activity as the default? both category and action?

Comment: ya.. after splashscreen, mainactivity should popup

Comment: have you made it?

Comment: yes it worked sorry for the late response. Thank you! Appreciated it!

Comment: Glad to help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked Sort / Alphabetical / Custom ?

Also Check `AndroidManifest.xml`

Main Activity Should Contains :

Like :

```
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So change `.SplashActivity` to that you want And Remember to place dot `.`  before it as i did

if you use `sub Package Name` place it , For Example :

your package is : `com.example.myapplication`

you create sub package as : `activities`

so in `AndroidManifest.xml` you have :

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: I had two activity one is the splash screen and one is my main activity file which one would I select as the launcher? Sorry new in Android native

Comment: You have to select splash screen as a lanucher

Comment: @JayzdeVera Sample changed , check it out

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the launcher activity for the app (in the `AndroidManifest.xml`)? If all else fails, you can also install the app manually using  [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)  (android debug bridge)
To install manually, Run this command from terminal/command prompt

```
adb install path_to_apk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxx"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="demo"
        android:exported="true" //
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When you apply `Android: exported="true"` to an `activity`, it becomes a public activity that can be called by other applications or components to initiate the `activity` and present it to the user.